# sudo still ask for password when NOPASSWD is used

Tags: linux, security, unix, sudo

I read all sudo posts on serverfault, but I still cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Normally I finally find the solution but not this time :

I want apache user to be able to execute this command as user "hremotessh" :

```
sudo /home/hremotessh/scripts/redirect.sh 8892 8893
```

Therefore I added this in visudo :

```
apache ALL=(hremotessh) NOPASSWD: /home/hremotessh/scripts/redirect.sh
```

But sudo is still asking the password ?

```
sudo /home/hremotessh/scripts/redirect.sh
[sudo] password for apache:
```

I tried this, but not better :

```
sudo -u hremotessh /home/hremotessh/scripts/redirect.sh
hremotessh is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Any idea would be warmly welcomed :-)

Denis

Comment: Did you definitely run the second `sudo` command as `apache`?

Comment: Flup, yes, at least I'm amost sure, I did the following from root :
    su - apache -s /bin/bash

Comment: you may find some info in /var/log/secure , did you check ?

Comment: db_ch, re Flup's comment, try again.  That error message **strongly** suggests you were the `hremotessh` user at the time.

Comment: What is the best way to be sure who I am logged in under ? At least what sudo is taking into account ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you want to run the command as root you need to specify the username, so

```
 su - apache -s /bin/bash 
 sudo -u hremotessh /home/hremotessh/scripts/redirect.sh 8892 8893
```

is the correct syntax to test the sudo command.

Since you're not prompted for the apache user's password sudo seems to be configured correctly.

The resulting warning: `hremotessh is not in the sudoers file.` indicates that another `sudo` command is used in the redirect.sh script. And there's no (valid) sudo policy for that user.

Comment: HBruijn makes a good point (+1 from me).  db_ch, could you edit the `/home/hremotessh/scripts/redirect.sh` script into your question?

Comment: Yes !!! Congratulations to HBruijn, stupid of me, I forgot to remove the sudo from /home/hremotessh/scripts/redirect.sh !

Thanks a lot everyone for your help !

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem when trying to run a python3 code as sudo from a script and cound't enter password from the script. The solution was to edit visudo so that python3 would run as sudo without prompting the password, NOT run the python3 script as sudo. So I believe you need to run apache as sudo without prompting for password, NOT running the .sh script as sudo without password.

Comment: editing visudo to fit your needs is a horrible idea.